# How to filter a Dashboard using a formula field?

Tags: formula-field, configuration, dashboard, custom-reports

I have a dashboard that I wish to display on clicking a link. This link has to be prepared in a way the dashboard filters and displays the components only for the products that are associated with the record but it is displaying for all the products. Attaching screenshots related to it.
Field Formula with the link
[image]

The Dashboard screenshot :
[image]

You can see there are multiple products but I'm trying to filter out with this 1 Product.

After editing and adding the filters
[image]

Edit 2 :
I changed the formula to the below
[image]

And I changed the filter in the dashboard also equally the Product Code in my Cart
[image]

So Now when I add the Item and I click on the Item it is opening correctly only for the item with that Product Code but I want it to open correctly for any code. I also want to bring another Customer filter. How can I make the filter work.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that your dashboard does not have any filters. You must create filters before you can use them. There is a special button in Dashboard-Edit mode to create filters.

Comment: @SanderdeJong But wouldn't it show only the filtered value ? For Example, If I filter with BOLT in the Dash and use it the formula. Wouldn't it become double filter on clicking a record with Cylinder Product type, after going thro' URL showing nothing.

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Sorry.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dashboards_filter_url.htm&type=5

Comment: @SanderdeJong Please find the new photo I added to the question description. I added the filters but I'm getting the error The filter URL is invalid Please Try Again on click the link and after opening. I also get nothing below the title of the dashbaord

Comment: @identigral Hi yes, by seeing the link u posted only I modified the formula but I'm getting some error.

Comment: You can't use the formula field you have in your question. Use the field that has your Product. Test it interactively in the dashboard then implement in the URL per the Help article. If you run into issues, please edit and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @identigral Hi It is working for only 1 Product as shown in modified question. How can I make it work for all the Products ?Like I want click on the button with any product and it should open by filtering the records for that Particular Product.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Can you have a look into this ? If you can not understand it, I'll add more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the filter value you are passing HAS to be a pre-defined selectable value in the dashboard filter(s).

You can not pass in anything you please.

I have created a reasonable solution (there are scaling limits) to this issue if you want to check it out on my blog here https://salesforceconfig.com/show-any-accounts-data-on-a-universal-dashboard/

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.